# Background Image not showing (Yes, I know it's been asked a lot) 2.79

Tags: image

Okay, so I've been researching this for hours, read multiple forums and everything is saying to switch to Orthographic View. I've tried this and have tried every angle possible. I'm sorry for posting a duplicate, but none of the solutions are working.

I've tried making a blank image and importing on top of it. I've checked the transparency. I've tried multiple images. The desired one is a 40KB JPG file and others attempted have been PNG as well varying in size. I'm completely out of ideas.

Thanks for taking time to read this.

[image: Orthographic View]

Comment: From the settings in your screenshot it should work. Please try a new Blender scene and do nothing accept enable the background image, add your image, set the camera orthographic and set the view Front. If that does not work then try a different image and use the File menu Load Factory Settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I finally had time to hop back in here and try what you suggested, but no go. I reset to factory settings, opened a new scene and switched to orthographic front view and the image still is not showing up.

Comment: that just does not make sense. can you use another computer? But just to be super duper clear. I reset factory settings, switched to cycles, opened the properties panel, enabled the background image, added an image and switched to orthographic and front view. The image clearly showed behind the default cube. Only thoughts are transparent or very small image hidden behind the mesh.

Comment: I just tried on my laptop as well and I'm getting the exact same issue. I've tried using 2.8 beta, but it's too different from 2.7, so I don't even know where to begin there.

I also just tried uninstalling 2.79 and installing 2.78 and the same issue's occurring.

I'm at a complete loss at this point.

Comment: OK here is my .blend file with the background setup, and view set up. Just open the file and you should see the default cube in Othorgraphic mode front view with a 2018 calendar image behind it. Image is packed in the .blend.

Comment: I'm not seeing any attachments or links to download the .blend file you mentioned. I may be missing something.

Comment: not sure where that link went, here it is again. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5573/

Comment: Ok, so I figured out the problem. Yours works fine. It turns out some of the files (coincidentally every single one that I was attempting) somehow had their file types corrupted. On Windows 10 the file type was set to .JPG in all uppercase, I've never seen this issue before and never even realized that this could even cause file extention issues.

So I went through and started comparing to other files of the same types, jpg, png, etc and they're working properly now (the ones that didn't somehow get corrupted).

Thanks for all of your time, rob. I appreciate your help.